# QT automation with pywinauto

Tags: python, qt, automation, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a QT app using pywinauto, the problem is pywinauto seems unable to click or select most objects and when it does they seem to be completely random to the ones I specified. Even using functions such as "**click_input**" execute properly, but the item is never actually clicked. Pywinauto apparently does recognize the button I'm trying to click and even prints it as an "**pywinauto.application.WindowSpecification**" object. I've noticed that pywinauto has some trouble with QT applications so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
anki_App = Application(backend="uia").start(anki_Path)
anki_App.top_window().wait("Visible") #Wait for Anki's sync to server
anki = anki_App.window(title_re=r".* - Anki", class_name="AnkiQt")
anki['Import File'].click_input()
```

Snippet from results of **anki.print_control_identifiers()** since the content is too large.

```
Button - 'Import File'    (L1751, T875, R1867, B910)
['Import File', 'Import FileButton', 'Button6']
child_window(title="Import File", control_type="Button")
```

Edit: Made some recommended changes, but the problem still remains. The click event doesn't seem to bring any errors yet no "click" actually happens.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, the second snippet is all the code, the first snipped shows the results of the print_control_identifiers function. anki_path is just the path to the application. https://apps.ankiweb.net/

Comment: Please provide full traceback. "Seem to fail" is not a technical term. Also `top_window()` is not recommended for use. It takes top window at the moment of its call. At another moment top window may change so you have to call `.top_window()` one more time. If the moment of top window change is random, your code would behave randomly!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the recommendation, that was another work around due to pywinauto's inability to find the required window. Again I'm unable to provide a traceback since the code runs smoothly without any visible errors.

Answer (score 1):

After asking around in Pywinsauto's github community I was able to solve it in the following way:

```
anki_App = Application(backend="uia").start(anki_Path)
anki_App.top_window().wait("Visible") #Wait for Anki's sync to server
anki = anki_App.window(title_re=r".* - Anki", class_name="AnkiQt")
anki['Browse'].click_input(coords=(anki['Browse'].rectangle().left -1, anki['Browse'].rectangle().top -1), absolute = True)
```

Problem was that the coordinates were wrong. They were pretty close though, so clicking the upper left corner was all that needed to be done. Again, many thanks to the user airelil for helping me figuring out the problem.

[Link to the issue](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/918)